# Javax publish two WSDL on 0.0.0.0

Tags: java, wsdl, java-8

when I try to publish 2 different WSDL on 0.0.0.0/8189 I'm getting error

```
Endpoint deployed: http://0.0.0.0:8189/termservice/soap/e?WSDL
Endpoint error: http://0.0.0.0:8189/termservice/soap/a?WSDL
Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

but when I doing this on one interface for example 127.0.0.1 it works fine.

```
Endpoint deployed: http://127.0.0.1:8189/termservice/soap/e?WSDL
Endpoint deployed: http://127.0.0.1:8189/termservice/soap/a?WSDL
```

I started to get this problem after upgrading to Java8

```
java -version

java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @JimW Hello there, solution to this problem is to add to ur hosts some domain name that point to 0.0.0.0 and run program with this domain name. e.g /etc/hosts got 0.0.0.0 test.dev entry then java -yourparam=test.dev